# Add Listener to Radio Buttons by Name

Tags: javascript, jquery, listener

I have some radio buttons as follows:

```
   <div class ="queryPropertiesSection" id="MapButtons">
        <div class="queryPropertiesLabel"> Map Type:</div>
        <input id="type1" type="radio" name="mapType" value="c"checked />Map 1
        <input id="type2" type="radio" name="mapType" value="d" />Map 2
    </div>
```

I want to add a listener to to those radio buttons using the name. I have seen this code:

```
$('input:radio').on('change', function(){
    //access value of changed radio group with $(this).val()
});
```

but there are multiple radio buttons on the page, so I do not think this will work. When I try

```
 $('name:mapType').on('change', function(){
        //access value of changed radio group with $(this).val()
    });
```

I get jquery error: `syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: mapType`. Is there a better way to add a listener to those radio buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this selector -

```
$('input:radio[name="mapType"]')
```

Comment: You can use more simple form $(':radio[name="mapType"]') :radio equal input[type="radio"]